# python pandas: set a value of column based on another value of a column in a list

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like as following:

```
        f1              f2              class              n
0   weekly_return   0.155796               ab            weekly
1   monthly_return  0.153907               ab            monthly
2   volume_ratio    0.123844               NaN           volume
3   margin_selling_balance  0.115411       ad            margin
4   margin_debt_balance 0.107883           ae            margin
5   rv_ratio    0.077373                   NaN            rv
..................................................................
```

and there is a list named lst_n as following:

```
lst_n = ['rv', 'ag', 'rg', ...........]
```

I want to set the the value of class column of this dataframe to 'class_a' if the value of n is in the lst_n. For example the fifth rows, the n is rv which is in the n list(lst_n), so the value of class is set to 'class_a'.
My code is following, but there is error:

```
  lst_n = ['rv', 'ag', 'rg', ...........]
  df.loc[df.n is in lst_n, 'class'] = 'class_a'
```

but there is error:

```
df.loc[df.n is in lst_n, 'class'] = 'class_a'
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for mask:

```
lst_n = ['rv', 'ag', 'rg']
df.loc[df['n'].isin(lst_n), 'class'] = 'class_a'
print (df)
                       f1        f2    class        n
0           weekly_return  0.155796       ab   weekly
1          monthly_return  0.153907       ab  monthly
2            volume_ratio  0.123844      NaN   volume
3  margin_selling_balance  0.115411       ad   margin
4     margin_debt_balance  0.107883       ae   margin
5                rv_ratio  0.077373  class_a       rv
```

Another solution with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['class'] = df['class'].mask(df.n.isin(lst_n), 'class_a')
print (df)
                       f1        f2    class        n
0           weekly_return  0.155796       ab   weekly
1          monthly_return  0.153907       ab  monthly
2            volume_ratio  0.123844      NaN   volume
3  margin_selling_balance  0.115411       ad   margin
4     margin_debt_balance  0.107883       ae   margin
5                rv_ratio  0.077373  class_a       rv
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a bit of performance, you can use np.where.

```
df['class'] = np.where(df.n.isin(lst_n), 'class_a', df['class'])

df
Out[942]: 
                       f1        f2    class        n
0           weekly_return  0.155796       ab   weekly
1          monthly_return  0.153907       ab  monthly
2            volume_ratio  0.123844      NaN   volume
3  margin_selling_balance  0.115411       ad   margin
4     margin_debt_balance  0.107883       ae   margin
5                rv_ratio  0.077373  class_a       rv
```